# How does one charge a 37-volt lithium battery?

Tags: lithium-ion, charger

I have removed a 37-volt lithium ion battery from a self-balancing scooter for a robotics project. I retained the PCBs of the device for charging the battery. Unfortunately, the electronics appear to be as dead as the battery now is. However, my search for an external charging solution (short of buying a lower-voltage battery or a new set of hoverboard PCBs) has been unfruitful. Below are my searches and their results (or the lack thereof).

[Lithium Battery Charger]

- Li-Po Chargers that max out at 22.2 volts.
- AA/AAA battery chargers.
- 12-volt Lithium-Ion chargers.
- Balancing Circuits.
- Power Tool batteries and chargers.

[37 Volt Lithium Battery Charger]

- Chargers of all sorts, but left out the decimal in "3.7" in the title.
- Hoverboard, Scooter, and Bike chargers that must plug into an assembled unit (not the lone battery).
- Balancing Circuits.
- Individual 3.7-volt cells.

The battery is a "Smart Lithium Ion Battery Pack" Model KY01, 37VDC 4Ah, 148Wh. It only has an XT60 connector; no balancing cord.

What solutions exist for my charging of this battery without any of the (functioning) original electronics?

Comment: Charge each cell individually...

Comment: it's a fire starter, don't cut corners.

Comment: Are you looking to buy a charger, or build one?

Answer (score 4):

The 36-37 VDC (nameplate) Li-Ion batteries are fairly common in electric scooters/ hoverboards e-bikes etc. etc. It looks like a typical Li-Ion 10S battery pack. There is a huge section of industry making them and equivalents. [Example](https://www.streetsaw.com/products/hoverboard-battery-replacement):

[image]

Since the battery is labeled as "smart battery" and has only 2 terminals, it means that all necessary balancing electronics is already built in, and the only thing you need is to get a proper AC-DC adapter/charger. [Typical chargers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B074SJT6ZT) provide 42V to charge these batteries, there are plenty of them on the market. From specs:

> INPUT SPEC:AC100-240V 50/60HZ
>
> charging voltage: DC42V
>
> charging current: 2A
>
> Charging mode: CC-CV

The "CC-CV" means that this is a full charger. All you need is to make an adapter between the XT60 and the barrel 5.5mm x 2.5mm jack.

Comment: *Slaps head to forehead* That is, nearly word-for-word, what came with it. Thanks!